# Contents of a view not displaying, simple app based on TODO tutorial, ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to create a simple TODO app based on the one in the Getting Started Ember.js tutorials, but with persistence to a backend.

I've had everything working until I wanted to look at wrapping my markup for rendering a todo in a view (called 'todo-element'), to enable drag & drop sorting.

Then, my view refused to render. I've simplified the markup for the view just to render the text 'Hello', to try to debug things. The instance of the view sets the tagName to 'li'. So I *should* be getting a list of lis with the text 'Hello' in them. However, all I get is a list of empty lis.

This is the markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Todos</title>
</head>
<body>


<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="todos">
  <section id="todos">
    <header>
      <h1>The TODOs</h1>
      {{input type="text" placeholder="Enter new TODO description here ..."
              value=newDescription action="createTodo"}}
      <button {{action "createTodo"}} id="add-todo">Add</button>
    </header>
    <ul id="todos">
      {{#each itemController="todo"}}
        {{todo-element}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </section>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="todo-element">
  <span>Hello</span>
</script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/handlebars-1.0.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/ember.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/ember-data.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/todos/app.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/todos/todo.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/todos/router.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/todos/todos_controller.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/todos/todo_controller.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/todos/todo_element_view.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/todos/edit_todo_view.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the code for the view:

```
Todos.TodoElementView = Ember.View.extend( {
  templateView : 'todo-element',
  tagName      : 'li'
} );

Ember.Handlebars.helper( 'todo-element', Todos.TodoElementView );
```

My best guess is that the 'todo-element' markup is not getting associated with the TodoElementView, as I get exactly the same empty list of lis if I change the 'todo-element' markup's data-template-name to something random.

If anybody could help me with where I'm going wrong here, I'd be very grateful.

Cheers,
   Doug.

Answer (score 0):

think you are little confused between ember components and ember views
1. A view is called with view helper {{view App.ViewName}}. Your code {{todo-element}} looks more like a component.

1. In your component you have a static tag span hello so I guess it's showing only hello. Put dynamic data in it using {{}}